# Package keyval Error: No value specified for trim

Tags: lyx

I am using Lyx and getting this error, and do not know how to resolve it. I do not even know which area of the document might be causing this. Please help? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably from some image that you included. Find an image, right-click on it, Settings..., and look for something referencing "trim" under the tabs, perhaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trim` option is typically associated with the inclusion of graphics as it - the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) - supports the `trim` key. Cycle through your images and right-click on them, choosing Settings... and going through the available options. Most likely there is something under the LaTeX and LyX options tab's LaTeX options...

[image]